# Print contents of a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

In C#, I have a panel on a form, the contents of which I want to print.  The contents of the panel are lines from the `DrawLines` method.

Currently I can't view in print preview or print the lines on the panel.  The border of the panel does appear.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);            
    panel1.CreateGraphics().DrawLines(new Pen(Color.Black),
      new Point[]{new Point(10,10),new Point(50,50)});
}

private void PrintPanel(Panel pnl)
{
  PrintDialog myPrintDialog = new PrintDialog();
  PrinterSettings values;
  values = myPrintDialog.PrinterSettings;
  myPrintDialog.Document = printDocument1;
  printDocument1.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
  printDocument1.PrintPage += 
    new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
  printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
  printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
  //printDocument1.Print();
  printDocument1.Dispose();
}
void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
  panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
}
```

Why are the lines in the panel not showing in print preview or printing?

Comment: Can't you simply share the drawing method of the panel between the panel and the `printPage` method?

Comment: That is a possibility. I was under the impression that the DrawToBitmap would have made a bitmap, thus saving me the need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing this.  Need to pass the graphics into the bitmap

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height, Panel1.CreateGraphics());
```

Comment: I still get a blank panel (both preview and printed)

Comment: yeah i see you are drawing to the bitmap from panel now.  seems like that should work

Answer (score -1):

It's because you use `CreateGraphics` in a wrong way and your draw is **cleared** unexpectedly, try drawing your stuff in a `Paint` event handler for your `panel1` like this:

```
//Paint event handler for your panel1
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){
  e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, new Point[]{new Point(10,10),new Point(50,50)});
}
```